# Shortest path which passes through a subset of vertices in an unweighted directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, graph-traversal

> Given an unweighted directed graph $G=(V, E)$, two vertices $s,t \in V$ and a subset of vertices $U \subseteq V$, suggest an algorithm which concludes if there exists a shortest path from $s$ to $t$ which passes through **all** the vertices in $U$.
>
> The time complexity of the algorithm should be $O(|V|+|E|)$.

I have found many similar but different questions on here, most either being weighted graphs or different in some other manner. From my understanding, there should be a more basic solution to this problem that satisfies the complexity demand.